# Searching for Files created but forgotten about and nested deep within other directories

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When installing a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 Pro it comes with many files and folders which are most often always in the same location with the same name etc.

If we create our own files and move them deep into some of the OS folders like **C:\Windows\servicing\Packages** and forget about them, is it possible to find these files via a search vector(keep in mind we do not know the name or locations as we have forgot)

The first search vector that comes to mind is that our files will not be default files which come with windows, however I dont know how we would include such a rule in a search.

Comment: So basically, you want to find all folders and files in the Windows directory that were added after Windows was installed, correct?

Comment: Why exactly are you manually putting files in protected folders?

Comment: @Ramhound: Hiding pr0n no doubt. ;)

Comment: @Karan - The protected folders are only write protected not read protected.

Comment: @Ramhound: Obviously, but the whole point behind *burying* them is so a casual user on a shared PC won't know or even come across them.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is using a "cutoff date," i.e. if you remember when you placed them there you could use Windows explorer let you search for them.

Another approach would be to copy the files coming from a fresh reference Windows installation onto an external harddisk (or use an sata adapter to connect the reference HD to your PC), then use a file sync tool like FreeFileSync - which has a compare mode - to let it show the files which are different.